# In React with Redux how to make double colons work

Tags: reactjs, redux, babeljs, ecmascript-next

I am trying to use ES2017 in my React project with webpack

I have a `.babelrc` file, and a `package.json`.

this is my `.babelrc` file:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2017"]
}
```

and this is `package.json`:

```
 {
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-async-functions": "^6.13.0",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-trailing-function-commas": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-es2017": "^6.22.0",
    "enzyme": "^2.4.1",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "^0.4.0",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "react": "^15.3.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.30.7",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.0",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
    "react-router": "^3.0.0",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.7",
    "redux": "^3.5.2",
    "redux-logger": "^2.6.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "test": "react-scripts test"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "./node_modules/react-scripts/config/eslint.js"
  }
}
```

When I am trying to use double colon, console reports syntax error

```
<div onMouseEnter={::this.mouseEnter()}>
</div>
```

anything wrong?

Comment: can anyone share a working copy of the config files?

Comment: i don't thing you are turning on right presets, https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2017/ mentions only two items it turns on and `::` is not in the list. Try to use [latest](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-latest/)

Comment: double colon is in the list of ES2016. But I want to use ES2017 directly

Comment: JavaScript has no `::` operator and maybe never will have one. I don't know how you got the impression that it's part of ES2017.

Answer (score 3):

In order to make use of the `::` operator to bind the function, you need to use the `babel-plugin-transform-function-bind` plugin.

Install it using the below command

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-function-bind
```

and then in your `.babelrc` include it as

```
{
    "presets": ["react", "stage-0", "es2015"],
    "plugins": ["transform-function-bind"]
 }
```

Make sure you install the above using

```
npm install -S babel-preset-stage-0 babel-preset-2015 babel-preset-react
```

`::` is the `ES2015+` function bind syntax and not `ES2017`

Read more about it **[here](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-function-bind/)** :

Comment: Do you have a working copy? can you share it? thanks

Comment: Unfortunately I don;t have a working copy, Are you getting the same error here. Can you share the image of the error

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer per se, but you can achieve similar behavior by declaring class methods as lambdas (or any other method mentioned [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html)) :

```
 export class MyComponent extends React.Component {

    mouseEnter = () => {
       console.log('hover');
    }
    render() {
       return <h1 onMouseEnter={this.mouseEnter}>hi!</h1>
    }

 }
```

Comment: I know it can be achieved by ES6 or even ES5. But I just want to use ES2017. Thanks all the same